# Question regarding parameters and variable selection in Mahout algorithm for logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

Below is the list of parameters in Mahout logistic regression.

1. What does "passes" mean? In detail please

   > --passes     passes                     the number of times to pass over the input data
2. What does "features" mean? Is it the number of variables I am taking as predictor? But I see people entering more or less at times for the number of variables.
3. Is there any way of selecting variables with good predictive power in machine learning something like ginie coeffecient?
4. How do we deal with multicollinearity in machine learning? Is it by regularisation?
   In statistics we remove the variable using variance inflation factor. Is it computed in machine learning?

   ```
   Command: mahout trainlogistic
   Flag       Any argument to flag     Description
   --help                              print this list
   --quiet                             be extra quiet
   --input       input                 where to get training data
   --output      output                where to get training data
   --target      target                the name of the target variable
   --categories  number                the number of target categories to be considered
   --predictors p [p ...]              a list of predictor variables
   --types      t [t ...]       a list of predictor variables types (numeric, word or text)
   --passes     passes                 the number of times to pass over the input data
   --lambda     lambda                 the amount of coeffiecient decay to use
   --rate       learningRate           the learning rate
   --noBias                            do not include a bias term
   --features   numFeatures            the number of internal hashed features to use
   ```

Comment: What is _Mahout_ logistic regression?  Why would you remove variables from the model?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Mahout is a software tool used in conjunction with Hadoop for machine learning and statistics.

Comment: Please describe the model it assumes and the objective criterion that is optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Passes means exactly what you say. The logistic regression module in mahout uses stochastic gradient descent to train, which means it goes through the data points one at a time, starting over when it reaches the end, until convergence. Number of passes is the number of times it has to start over.

Features does mean the variables used as predictors. I don't know what you mean by people entering more or less at times.

Logistic regression in machine learning is exactly the same as logistic regression in statistics. Literally they are exactly the same. You can use regularization to select variables, or you can take them one by one using some metric (such as AIC, BIC, etc...) but you ahve to calculate them yourself if you're using mahout. It wont' do that for you (AFAIK).

Multicolinearity is dealt with in ML by, one hopes, having enough data. If you're so inclined you can calculate a VIF and use that, but if I recall correctly that is not trivial in the case of a logistic model.

Finally, if you want that text string at the bottom to be of any help you will need to provide some context about what exactly that is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

--passes : think of this as the number of times you want to loop over the data

features : if you a have a dataset with column names "name","id","age" etc., then "name","id","age" etc., are the features that you can use as predictors or a target variable.

Q 3,4: I think these depend on what you want to predict. You might want to tweak the learning rate and double check the values returned. I am trying to figure this out as well, so am not cent percent sure.